# A method of comparing two samples probabilistically

Tags: probability, distributions

I'm stuck when looking at the following problem say I have two samples of different sizes drawn from a continuous distribution.

$(x_1,x_2,...,x_k)$ and $(y_1, y_2,..., y_m)$

What would be the best way to evaluate the probability that they are both drawn from the same distribution?

Answer (score 2):

I think a classical approach is Kolmogorov Smirnov two sample test. See wikipedia [dedicated page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test). Basically the KS 2-sample test the null hypothesis that both samples were drawn from the same distribution. However you can consider more powerful and insightful modern methods like this one described [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/comparing-all-quantiles-of-two-distributions-simultaneously/) which compares the quantiles of both distributions. The last method gives more information related with how the differences are structured, if there are significant differences.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) and Wald-Wolfowitz two sample runs test.

Both are non-parametric tests that can be used with unequal sample sizes. The samples being tested are assumed to be independent of each other.

The test will give you a p-value; it will tell you how likely it is to get this large a test statistic (or larger) if the two samples were actually drawn from the same population.